# Search a "String" in folder containing zips of text files

Tags: linux, shell, grep, zip

I am looking for the files having string say "My_Name" In my backup folder of Linux server. where I have zip of works of every day. like MyWork_20180306.zip.

Searching in one zip file would be enough. because there are 100 of zips with name pattern MyWork_yyyymmdd.zip.

I am using below command, which is working fine on folder of documents. but not in zip.

```
cd /path/
grep -Ril "My_Name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep), which has the same semantics as `grep`, but can search within compressed files:

```
$ zgrep -Ril "My_Name"
```

Comment: Getting msg R is not supported, Can you include file name in your command?

Comment: This answer is not correct. zgrep does not work with zip files.